# Unable to separate valid and invalid file in unix script topic

Tags: text-processing, scripting, csv

I have three files named as `a.csv`, `b.csv`, and `c.csv`.

`a.csv` has content

```
1234567,11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

`b.csv` has content like

```
1234567845610111211111111111111111111111111
```

`c.csv` has content

```
111111,22222222,3333333,,,44444444444444444444
```

From the above mentioned three files I require only `a.csv` which means file with two column which should not contain any null values and remaining files (`b.csv` and `c.csv`) which has to loaded into another text file example `List.txt` which has `b.csv` and `c.csv` file.

I have tried below command to eliminate file with no comma (`,`), that is `b.csv`, but I required to consider `c.csv` as well as invalid

```
grep -v "," *.csv |cut -d ":" -f1
```

As suggested, I have tried below command and it works it displays files with two column value

```
awk -F"," 'NF==2 {print FILENAME}' *.csv
```

but I required to write invalid files too into another files please give me some suggestion.

Tried below by suggestion but it didn't work

```
ls | grep -v $(awk -F"," 'NF==2 {print FILENAME}') *.csv|sort -u
```

I have also been suggested to try

```
awk -F',' 'BEGINFILE{ok=1}!$1||!$2||NF!=2{ok=0; nextfile}ENDFILE{if(!ok)print FILENAME}' *.csv
```

But that results in below error:

```
awk: A statement occurred that is not valid.

 The input line number is 1. The file is <Filename>
 The source line number is 1.
```

Please be informed my  2nd field value is of 250 character length and have n number of files similar to `a.csv`,`b.csv` ...

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you want to find files that do _not_ have empty fields, and that do _not_ have lines with just a single field?  Do all your files contain only a single line? Can we assume that you have many more files than the three files that you mention?

Comment: 1. First field max length of 14 and second field max length of 150  2.Yes have multiple files similar to a.csv,b.csv and c.csv 3.i require to capture files which has more than two fields value

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly that you want to discard any file which contains any line where any of the following is true
:

1. Field 1 is empty `!$1`
2. Field 2 is empty `!$2`
3. There are not 2 fields `NF!=2`

Then

```
awk -F',' 'BEGINFILE{ok=1}!$1||!$2||NF!=2{ok=0; nextfile}ENDFILE{if (ok) print FILENAME}' *.csv
```

Which simply sets the `ok=1` flag and then loops over each line until any of the above conditions are true and, as soon as it finds a "bad" line invalidates the file by `ok=0` and skips to the end of the file without parsing more lines `nextfile`.

At the end of each file `ENDFILE` it only prints the `FILENAME` when `if (ok)` is non-zero

So to negate the match just invert the last test to `if (!ok)`for printing

```
awk -F',' 'BEGINFILE{ok=1}!$1||!$2||NF!=2{ok=0; nextfile}ENDFILE{if (!ok) print FILENAME}' *.csv
```

**Edit**

I can't reproduce the failure in output on my `gawk` (see below including redirection of filenames to xxx.file)

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

awk --version
GNU Awk 5.1.0, API: 3.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.2.0)

tail -n +1 *.csv; 
  awk -F',' 'BEGINFILE{ok=1}
    !$1||!$2||NF!=2{ok=0; nextfile}
  ENDFILE{gzout=(ok)?"ok":"banjaxed"; print FILENAME > gzout".files"}' *.csv ; 
tail -n +1 *.files

==> a.csv <==
1234567,11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

==> b.csv <==
1234567845610111211111111111111111111111111

==> c.csv <==
111111,22222222,3333333,,,44444444444444444444

==> banjaxed.files <==
b.csv
c.csv

==> ok.files <==
a.csv
```

Individual field length limits (1024) [should not be an issue](http://web.deu.edu.tr/doc/oreily/unix/sedawk/ch10_08.htm) for `awk`unless you break the 3,000 character record limit, in which case neither `awk` nor `sed` seem to be the tools for the job.

Comment: But not  working

Comment: Worked fine copy pasting the sample in your post into local files. Any output? No Output?

Comment: edited question No output came

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative using `grep` and assuming that neither `sed` nor `grep` can be used and that you have **thousands** of files each one **thousands** of lines long, so you only want to inspect the very first line of each, rather than `grep`ping them all the way through.....

Grab all of the first lines (with the file name) and throw them into a file

```
head -n1 *.csv > list
```

Each entry has one line of context (the file name), the first line and a blank line after, like this

```
==> a.csv <==
1234567,11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

==> b.csv <==
1234567845610111211111111111111111111111111
```

You know the pattern for conforming lines is `^[0-9.]+,[0-9.]+$`and so you can

```
grep -E -B1 "^[0-9]+,[0-9]+$" list | grep -oP "(?<= )[^, <]+" > ok.list
```

The first `grep` pulls out the matches from `list` with one line of context before `-B1` (the filename containing the match) and the second strips out the filenames and dumps them into the file you want `ok.list`

Finally you can use the `ok.list` to filter

```
ls *.csv | grep -Fvxf ok.list > banjaxed.list
```

Where you just use `grep` to filter out the files in `ok.list` from the ones from `ls` on fixed strings (not regex) '-F', exact matches only `-x` using the files `-f` as a list of patterns to match and, of course inverting `-v` the match finally redirecting the filtered list to `banjaxed.list`

If that's not worth at least something, then I am packing up my toys.